# Using built in general midi on OS X using RtMidi?

Tags: c++, macos, midi

I'm trying to write a C++ app which plays midi sounds, but I'm having some difficulty.  I got the examples that come with RtMidi to compile out of the box, but running the midiout example, I don't hear anything.  Running the midiprobe example I get:

```
There are 1 MIDI input sources available.
  Input Port #1: AudioFire4 (2357) Plug 1

There are 1 MIDI output ports available.
  Output Port #1: AudioFire4 (2357) Plug 1
```

But that's just an audio interface that I use for using multiple speakers.  I don't use any of the midi functionality on it.

Does anyone know how to get RtMidi to use the built in system general midi sound bank so that I can actually hear something?

Thanks,
Gabe

Comment: From what I understand (and I may be very out of date here), there isn't a built-in fake MIDI out for playing general MIDI; you need to explicitly create a QuickTime Music Synthesizer instance, then create a "virtual MIDI port" that connects to the QTMS instance, and then use that as your MIDI out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is curious about this, I ended up installing FluidSynth and downloading the FluidR3 soundfont.  That seems to work great.  Just run it, and it presents itself as a midi device.